# Customers mandatory have to create an account to pay by cb?

Tags: paypal

I'm implementing Paypal Express Checkout on my website and playing with it, I notice that we can freely pay by CB, just giving our email address on the english page and we mandatory have to create an account on the french page.
Is it a mistake or intentional?

Comment: Not sure what a CB is.  If you are looking at just the translated page for paying the same seller, language should not affect functionality so there should be no difference. However, the country of the payer, the country of the seller, and various settings/options on the seller's account could affect whether a buyer can pay without an account. Also note that cookies influence the presentation of the page, so you can see differences from that alone.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to talk about CC payment. So I don't know about other parameters, I just changed en_US to fr_FR in the button link.

Comment: Changing the localization from US to France does signal PayPal to provide potentially different behavior (e.g. presenting French payment method selections to customers). So while I do not know the particulars of PayPal's business logic for France, you may be seeing the intended behavior.

Comment: Well, thanks geewiz. I will try to test on french merchant websites to verify it but I'm almost sure that it was possible to pay directly by credit card without creating an account not so long time ago...

Comment: My point is that both the country of the buyer and the seller matter for this. So testing other French merchants is not the same as testing a french buyer. E.g. a UK buyer should be presented the option to pay with a Switch or Solo card when paying any merchant (US, UK, French, etc). And a North Korean buyer must be blocked regardless of seller country (US regulations). Etc. But if you want an authoritative answer about PayPal policies for French users, ask PayPal.

Comment: Strangely,I implemented express checkout on my website with their well done wizard and it perfectly allows to pay with creditcard without creating an account.